# INDEX, EQUIV and chose the range that is used

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I chose countries/cities in **E13**
Then there is a drop-down list in **G13** with the list of the countries OR cities. (depend of what I chose)

Now I have a result in **G18** who is using `INDEX EQUIV`.

```
=INDEX(Données!H$6:$H$133;
EQUIV(G9&G11&G12&G13&G14&G15&G16;Données!A6:A133&Données!B6:B133&Données!C6:C133&Données!D6:D133&Données!E6:E133&Données!F6:F133&Données!G6:G133;0)
)
```

But I want that if it's countries then the `INDEX EQUIV` chose **Range Données!E6:E133**

OR if it's cities then the `INDEX EQUIV` chose **Range Données!F6:F133**

To conclud I have 1 critera and 2 ranges.
Depending on what is in **E13** (countries/cities), it chose the range.

Comment: for those in the dark, EQUIV is the FR-FR of the EN-US MATCH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an IF statement checking the value in E13 to determine whether to use Données!F6:F133 or Données!E6:E133.

```
=INDEX(Données!H$6:$H$133;
   EQUIV(G9&G11&G12&G13&G14&G15&G16; Données!A6:A133&Données!B6:B133&Données!C6:C133&Données!D6:D133&
if(E13="cities"; Données!F6:F133; Données!E6:E133) &Données!G6:G133; 0))
```